# Does a charged particle traveling perpendicular to a uniform electric field gain energy?

Tags: electrostatics, particle-physics, electric-fields

Does a charged particle traveling along the y-axis with a constant velocity $v_0$, who enters a uniform electric field pointing at the x direction (i.e perpendicular to the electric field) gain kinetic energy by the time it leaves the electric field?

Comment: Jokerp, I've downvoted your question for the "Does not show any research effort" reason. You might find the following link helpful:  [How do I ask a good question?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - *"Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The particle will accelerate in the $x$-direction (or negative $x$-direction if the charge is negative) due to the electric force. This will increase the $x$-component of its velocity so that its overall velocity and thus kinetic energy will increase.

Where does the energy come from you may ask? The charged particle has an electric potential energy and this is lost as it is accelerated in the direction of the field - converted into kinetic energy. This is just like how a stationary ball gains kinetic energy from rolling down a hill. In that case gravitational potential energy is converted into kinetic energy.

Comment: A textbook problem and answer, but it ignores what happens when the particle (instantaneously?) enters and leaves the field. Does conservation of energy imply that the speed before entering and after leaving are equal?

Comment: @Peter The potential energy is converted to kinetic energy so it leaves with the same amount of total energy (less potential and more kinetic).

Comment: The problem is that another charge might follow a path around the field (diverted by magnetic fields which do not change its pe or ke). This second charge would have a lower ke afterwards, but in the same position would have the same pe. I believe pe is added on entering the field, and on exiting enough pe and ke are lost to restore the original energy

Answer (score 0):

The electric field must be provided by some device, for example a pair of fixed, charged parallel plates.

For a pair of charged plates the charged particle might or might not change its potential energy as it approaches the plates, depending on its path. Between the plates it will move nearer one of them, and accelerate. In other words it is changing potential energy into kinetic energy. As it departs the space between the plates its potential energy will begin to return to its original value. Its distance from the attracting plate will increase more than its distance from the other, and it will slow down again. It will eventually return to its original speed.